# How I can hide the part of element that is outside of Scene? JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene

This is a situation very hard to explain , i'm going to do the best.

I need to do a circular Pane or a Scene that hide the part of the element (node) that is outside of the area of the Circle. I mean, I don't want to HIDE the FULL ELEMENT only the zone outside. Like a ".setClip". I cant use this last method, because the project is an animation and when I move the node the clip move too.

This is what I want to make, when the text come up.

[Example](http://www.android.com/new/videos/wear1.webm)

Here is a image from my project. The red's marks show the problem.

[image]

Thanks!

PD: Here is the DocumentController [Link](http://txt.do/6k6r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with setClip()? If the following doesn't give you the answer you need, please provide a full code example which shows the problem.

Clip the image (ie without text)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClipImage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        // background image
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

        // some text
        Label label = new Label( "This is a Tiger. Tigers are awesome!");
        label.relocate(20, 400);
        label.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 48));

        root.getChildren().addAll( imageView, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        public CirclePane() {

            // load image
//          ImageView imageView = new ImageView( getClass().getResource("tiger.jpg").toExternalForm());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

            // create circle
            Circle circle = new Circle( 200);
            circle.relocate(200, 100);

            // clip image by circle
            imageView.setClip(circle);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            // new image from clipped image
            WritableImage wim = null;
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            // new imageview
            ImageView clippedView = new ImageView( wim);

            // some shadow
            clippedView.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.BLACK));

            clippedView.relocate( 200, 100);

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y));

    }


}
```

[image]

Just click on the face and drag it around.

Or you snapshot the entire scene and clip it, so you have everything in the new image:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClipScene extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        Group root = new Group();

        // background image
//      ImageView imageView = new ImageView( getClass().getResource("tiger.jpg").toExternalForm());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

        // some text
        Label label = new Label( "This is a Tiger. Tigers are awesome!");
        label.relocate(20, 400);
        label.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 48));

        root.getChildren().addAll( imageView, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        public CirclePane() {

            WritableImage wim = null;

            // load image
            wim = primaryStage.getScene().snapshot( wim);

            // create imageview
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView( wim);

            // create circle
            Circle circle = new Circle( 200);
            circle.relocate(200, 100);

            // clip image by circle
            imageView.setClip(circle);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            // new image from clipped image
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            // new imageview
            ImageView clippedView = new ImageView( wim);

            // some shadow
            clippedView.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.BLACK));

            clippedView.relocate( 200, 100);

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y));

    }


}
```

[image]

Here's the animated version where the background scrolls vertically:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClipImage extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        Group root = new Group();

        // background image
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/640px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg");

        root.getChildren().addAll( imageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                circlePane.scroll();                
            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        double y = 0;
        ImageView clippedView;
        ImageView imageView;
        Circle circle;
        SnapshotParameters parameters;
        WritableImage wim = null;

        boolean directionForward = true;

        public CirclePane() {

            imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/640px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg");

            // create circle
            circle = new Circle( 100);
            circle.relocate(200, 100);

            // clip image by circle
            imageView.setClip(circle);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            // new image from clipped image
            wim = null;
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            // new imageview
            clippedView = new ImageView( wim);

            // some shadow
            clippedView.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.BLACK));

            clippedView.relocate( 150, 100);

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

        public void scroll() {

            if( directionForward) {
                y++;
                if( y > 100) {
                    directionForward = false;
                }
            } else {
                y--;
                if( y < 0) {
                    directionForward = true;
                }
            }

            circle.relocate(150, 100 + y);
            imageView.setClip(circle);
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);
            clippedView.setImage( wim);
        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y));

    }


}
```

[image]

And the same with text, in which the scene is used to create a combined snapshot of imageview and label.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClipScene extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        Group root = new Group();

        // background image
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/640px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg");

        // some text
        Label label = new Label( "Let the sun shine!");
        label.relocate(180, 220);
        label.setTextFill(Color.YELLOW);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 18));

        root.getChildren().addAll( imageView, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

//      label.setVisible(false);
//      imageView.setVisible(false);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                circlePane.scroll();                
            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        double y = 0;
        ImageView clippedView;
        ImageView imageView;
        Circle circle;
        SnapshotParameters parameters;
        WritableImage wim = null;

        boolean direction = true;

        public CirclePane() {

            WritableImage wim = null;

            // load image
            wim = primaryStage.getScene().snapshot( wim);

            imageView = new ImageView( wim);

            // create circle
            circle = new Circle( 100);
            circle.relocate(200, 100);

            // clip image by circle
            imageView.setClip(circle);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            // new image from clipped image
            wim = null;
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            // new imageview
            clippedView = new ImageView( wim);

            // some shadow
            clippedView.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.BLACK));

            clippedView.relocate( 150, 100);

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

        public void scroll() {

            if( direction) {
                y++;
                if( y > 100) {
                    direction = false;
                }
            } else {
                y--;
                if( y < 0) {
                    direction = true;
                }
            }

            circle.relocate(150, 100 + y);
            imageView.setClip(circle);
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);
            clippedView.setImage( wim);
        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y));

    }


}
```

[image]

And here's all combined, where the animated sunset is "rendered" offscreen, ie we use a Pane for the snapshot, not the Scene:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClipOffScreen extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        // background image
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/800px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");

        // some text
        Label label = new Label( "This is a Tiger. Tigers are awesome!");
        label.relocate(20, 400);
        label.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 48));

        root.getChildren().addAll( imageView, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // pane with clipped area
        CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
        makeDraggable( circlePane);

        root.getChildren().addAll( circlePane);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                circlePane.scroll();                
            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private class CirclePane extends Pane {

        double y = 0;
        ImageView clippedView;
        ImageView imageView;
        Circle circle;
        SnapshotParameters parameters;
        WritableImage wim = null;

        boolean direction = true;

        public CirclePane() {

            Pane offScreenPane = new Pane();

            // background image
            ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Sunset_2007-1.jpg/640px-Sunset_2007-1.jpg");

            // some text
            Text text = new Text( "Let the sun shine!");
            text.relocate(180, 220);
            text.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            text.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 18));

            offScreenPane.getChildren().addAll( imageView2, text);

            // non-clip area should be transparent
            parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

            WritableImage wim = null;

            // load image
            wim = offScreenPane.snapshot( parameters, wim);

            imageView = new ImageView( wim);

            // create circle
            circle = new Circle( 100);
            circle.relocate(200, 100);

            // clip image by circle
            imageView.setClip(circle);



            // new image from clipped image
            wim = null;
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);

            // new imageview
            clippedView = new ImageView( wim);

            // some shadow
            clippedView.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.BLACK));

            clippedView.relocate( 150, 100);

            getChildren().addAll( clippedView);

        }

        public void scroll() {

            if( direction) {
                y++;
                if( y > 100) {
                    direction = false;
                }
            } else {
                y--;
                if( y < 0) {
                    direction = true;
                }
            }

            circle.relocate(150, 100 + y);
            imageView.setClip(circle);
            wim = imageView.snapshot(parameters, wim);
            clippedView.setImage( wim);
        }

    }

    // make node draggable
    class DragContext { 
        double x;
        double y; 
    } 

    public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

        final DragContext dragDelta = new DragContext();

        node.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

            dragDelta.x = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();

        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> node.relocate( mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x, mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y));

    }


}
```

The trick is to use Text instead of Label, because Label will be hidden if it isn't visible. I guess that's some kind of JavaFX internal optimization.

[image]

Comment: Hi Roland! Thanks for your answer. Your code is very good, but I need to animate the Text with PathTransition, appearing from bottom to top. With snapshots this can't be do (I think). And the problem is when the transition start from bottom, there are some letters that are outside of the scene. You understand ?

Comment: I did a [example](http://textuploader.com/6kl1) to show you with a Image (Which is same situation for text). When I start the PathTransition, this move the "clip" instead of the image. I want to move only the image, not the clip.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend! Hope one day I can know you in person and learn more from you :) // One question about the method "scroll" is there a way to make the transition more "soft" in the end ? (I never did a animation without using PathTransition LOL). THANKS AGAIN <3

Comment: You're welcome. You'd have to change the y value in a non-linear way. Or you could use an Interpolator (just google for "JavaFX Interpolator")